# SQL Server is removing my leading zeros on varchar column

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert data to a column that is varchar(50), but randomly SQL Server removes the leading zeros.

I did the insert of the "1471" manually, like this:

```
insert into X (ds_code_product) values ('001471')
```

but SQL did '1471'

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the Create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT](
    [CD_PRODUCT] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DS_CODE_PRODUCT] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [NM_PRODUCT] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [DS_CODE_SUPPLIER] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CD_COMPANY_UNIT] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [VL_STATUS] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [DT_READ] [datetime] NULL,
    [DT_CREATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TP_PRODUCT] [varchar](1) NULL DEFAULT ('1'),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PRODUCT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CD_PRODUCT] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Identificador do Produto' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'CD_PRODUCT'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Código do Produto ERP' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'DS_CODE_PRODUCT'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Descrição do Produto' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'NM_PRODUCT'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Código do Fornecedor ERP' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'DS_CODE_SUPPLIER'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Código da Filial' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'CD_COMPANY_UNIT'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Status de importação:
(1) importado pelo ERP com sucesso.
(2) importado pelo ERP inconsistência.
(3)Lido com sucesso pela automação.
(4)lido automação com inconsistência.
' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'VL_STATUS'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Data da Leitura' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'DT_READ'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Data da Importação' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'DT_CREATE'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Tipo de Produto:
1 - Geral (Valor Padrão)
2-  Matéria-Prima
3 - Produto Final 
' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'TP_PRODUCT'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Tabela de Produtos' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PRODUCT'
GO
```

Full insert:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (DS_CODE_PRODUCT, NM_PRODUCT, DS_CODE_SUPPLIER, CD_COMPANY_UNIT, VL_STATUS, DT_CREATE, TP_PRODUCT)
VALUES ('001441','TORTA DE ALGODAO GRANEL','-1',22,1,'2016/03/09','2')
```

Comment: I don't it will happen unless datatype is of `Integer` or `numeric` type or you data is inserted without quotes

Comment: Are you posting the exact insert statement? A simple reproduction of your scenario does not yield this issue - `CREATE TABLE #X (ds_code_product VARCHAR(50)); INSERT #X (ds_code_product) VALUES ('001471'); SELECT * FROM #X; DROP TABLE #X`

Comment: Please show your table schema, including any constraints or triggers, as @GarethD stated this is unable to be reproduced with what you've shown in your question.

Comment: Ok just edited the post with create and insert statements @GarethD

Comment: @LeandroDaminelli Do you have triggers? Show also  query to retrieve data.

Comment: `SELECT DS_CODE_PRODUCT,LEN(DS_CODE_PRODUCT), DATALENGTH(DS_CODE_PRODUCT) FROM [dbo].[PRODUCT] WHERE CD_PRODUCT = 41`

Comment: @lad2025 No triggers.
Here is your query:
DS_CODE_PRODUCT (No column name) (No column name)
1471 4 4

Comment: I rather would have assumed that you forgot the apostrophes in the original `insert into X (ds_code_product) values (001471)`.

Comment: @Ralph I didn't. See my entire post where I show the full insert that I'm using

Comment: @LeandroDaminelli Do you insert data using SSMS or client aplication?

Comment: @lad2025 tried both. I dropped the table and recreated it. Now seems it's working fine, but I still want to know wtf happened